# Comparing Different Excel Permutations

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 4 subjects that can be graded i.e. Math's, Science, English, Geography.
Each subject is graded on a proficiency scale from 1-5, i.e PS1, PS2, PS3, PS4, PS5, where PS2 is better than PS1, PS3 is better than PS2 and so on.

To pass, students would need to score at least 2 PL2 and 2 PL1 (in any combination for all 4 subjects).

| Student | Maths | Science | English | Social Studies | Expected Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Anna | PS2 | PS1 | NA | PS3 | Fail |
| Ben | PS2 | PS4 | PS1 | PS3 | Pass |
| Clare | PS1 | PS1 | PS3 | PS3 | Pass |

How can I write an excel formula to generate column F "Expected Result"?

Comment: Clare passes with two PS1, but why Ben? Only difference between Ben and Anna is an NA...

Comment: To pass, one would need 2 PS2 and 2 PS1. Ben received 1PS1, 1PS2, 1PS3 and 1PS4 . His PS3 and PS4 grades are higher than the passing score hence he would also pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(B2:E2,">=PS1")=4,COUNTIF(B2:E2,">PS1")>1),"Pass","Fail")
```